# Using nested each() in JQUERY to Calculate Cumulative Content Height

Tags: jquery, html, height, each, cumulative-sum

I am trying to work out a resize function to increase the height of a div container (in each case here, "div.cell") if the screen is scrunched so much that the contents spill out.  Each div.cell has a bunch of different p's.  Here are just 2.

```
    <div class="cell panel">
        <img src="stills/press/press-logo-c2e2.png" class="general"><p class="one">Panelist - Chicago Comic & Entertainment Expo</p>
        <p class="two">[Panel Name Here]</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panel Date/Location:</b> [Time]PM on April 26-28, 2013 at C2E2 (Chicago, Illinois)</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panelists:</b> [Panelists]</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panel Blurb:</b> "[Blurb]"</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cell panel">
        <img src="stills/press/press-logo-wondercon-anaheim.png" class="general"><p class="one">Panelist - WonderCon</p>
        <p class="two">[Panel Name Here]</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panel Date/Location:</b> [Time]PM on March 29-31, 2013 at WonderCon (Anaheim, California)</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panelists:</b> [Panelists]</p>
        <p class="three"><b>Panel Blurb:</b> "[Blurb]"</p>
    </div>
```

In super rudimentary, and very wrong, jquery, I was hoping to nest to do this, such as:

```
var pheight = 0;
var divheight = 0;
var biggest = 0;
$("div.cell").each(function (){
    divheight=$(this).height();
    pheight = 0;
    $("p").each(function (){
        pheight += $(this).height();
    });
    biggest = divheight;
    if (pheight > biggest) { biggest = pheight };
    $(this).css("height",biggest);
})
```

This doesn't work :)  Anyone know how I can change each div.cell to be the cumulative height of its p's (plus a buffer)

Comment: Can you show us an example of it not working?  Looks valid to me

Comment: should probably move your `var`'s into the `each` so they reset on each pass , although I don't think will be problem as is

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    //your script here
});
```

it will bind your function to window resize event, but I don't think your function work right, it will only increase the height, and never decrease it.
ps: sorry, I can't post comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want. But you may have a try to this code:

```
var pheight = 0;
var divheight = 0;
var biggest = 0;
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("div.cell").each(function () {
        //divheight=$(this).height();
        pheight = 0;
        $(this).find("p,img").each(function () {
            pheight += $(this).height();
        });
        biggest = pheight;
        //if (pheight > biggest) { biggest = pheight };
        $(this).css("height", biggest);
    });
});
```

Here is jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/agAm8/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, maybe this would help:

```
var pheight = 0;
var divheight = 0;
var biggest = 0;
$("div.cell").each(function () {
    divheight = $(this).height();
    pheight = 0;
    $(this).children("p").each(function () {
        pheight += $(this).height();
    });
    biggest = divheight;
    if (pheight > biggest) {
        biggest = pheight;
    }
    $(this).css("height", biggest);
});
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RLWqV/